# Spring's Stored Procedure, parsing the result Map

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, stored-procedures, dictionary

I've got a setup with Spring & Hibernate over MySQL.
I have a MySQL Stored-Procedure I would like to call.
The procedure takes 2 float arguments, and returns a result-set with 3 fields. Integer,Integer,Float.

I created a class which extends spring's StoredProcedure.
This is the execute function:

```
public Map execute(float longitude, float latiude) {
Map inparams = new HashMap(2);
inparams.put("longitude", (float) longitude);
inparams.put("latitude", (float) latiude);
Map out = execute(inparams);
```

The problem is that I don't know how to parse the map result.
When I'm debugging, I see that all the result-set is in there, but It arranged in a strange way, and I don't know how to extract the fields.

The best I can do to show you how it looks, is to give you the toString() of out (Map)
Here it is:

> {#result-set-1=[{id=4, out1=100, distance=40.9}, {id=5, out1=100,
>   distance=47.7}, {id=6, out1=100, distance=22.3}, {id=7, out1=100,
>   distance=27.4}, {id=8, out1=100, distance=22.1}, {id=9, out1=100,
>   distance=18.3}, {id=10, out1=100, distance=20.1}, {id=11, out1=100,
>   distance=28.6}, {id=12, out1=100, distance=23.1}], #update-count-1=0}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd look in a debugger to see what the types are; IntelliJ could tell me this easily.

It looks like a `Map<String, Object>` to me.  The keys are "#result-set-1" and "#update-count-1".

The value for the first key is a List of Maps, one Map per row returned.  The keys are the column names and the values are the returned values.

The value for the second key is an Integer; it's zero because you did a SELECT.

So, in the interest of spelling it out, here's how to extract your results (sorry for the initial coding error):

```
// Foo is some unknown object that encapsulates each row.
List<Foo> results = new ArrayList<Foo>();
Map<String, Object> rows = (Map<String, Object>) out.get("#result-set-1");
for (Map row : rows) {
    int id = row.get("id");
    int out1 = row.get("out1");
    double distance = row.get("distance");
    results.add(new Foo(id, out1, distance));
}
return results;
```

Comment: It doesn't compile, Actually I don't really understand what you're doing in the for statement, what's this ? "Map row : out.get..."

Comment: Sorry, too foggy at that hour.  I think this is correct.  The idea was to get the List of rows out of the result Map and iterate over its collection of Maps.  The words are correct; the code was wrong.

Comment: It wasn't wrong six years ago when I answered this question.  I ran the code in an IDE and debugger!  If the API has changed, that's not my fault.  Go check Jon Skeet's old answers and tell him when he's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Spring you can use the Jackson ObjectMapper.
It's more simple than the first answer.

```
class Foo {
  private int id;
  private int out1;
  private double distance;
  // getters and setters
}
```

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Foo> list = objectMapper.convertValue(execute.get("#result-set-1"), new TypeReference<List<Foo>>() {});
```

I hope that helps even if this question is open for a long time :)